# Spark + Play JSON dependency conflict

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, playframework

I am currently trying to parse json from my RDD object, for this I intend to use the Play Json library. 
However, once I try to run my code, I get the following error:

> Incompatible Jackson version: 2.8.9

**I was wondering if there is any way to work around this while still using both libraries or if I must change my json library and opt for something else?**

My current versions are as follows:

[image: Current external libraries]

And I am also using IntelliJ IDEA

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Any luck with solving this issue? I am also facing the same issue and have been stuck

Comment: Sorry, this was a long time ago and don't remember how I solved it. Judging from what I marked as answer, I opted for using the Spark JSON library. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any reason why you are using the play framework to parse JSON in Spark ? I can't think of any. Spark can deal with JSON without the need for the Play framework.

In fact, the issue you're experiencing is caused precisely by a conflict between the Play jackson version and the one that is used by Spark.

If you're reading JSON data you can instead:

- read a JSON file directly with something like `val peopleDF = spark.read.json(path)`
- if you already have an RDD and need to parse JSON from one or more fields you can use the functions `from_json` etc that you can find [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) in the Spark API docs.

I don't know which one would fit best since you didn't include any example code.

Comment: You're right, that sounds like a much better option!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use latest [jackson-module-scala](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala) if you are not going to waste your CPU by parsing or serializing with play-json.

[Here](http://jmh.morethan.io/?source=https://plokhotnyuk.github.io/jsoniter-scala/jdk8.json) are results of [benchmarks](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/tree/a600f60825bbc3d0dab53fa6d97e2bcc280cb1ae/benchmark/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/macros) that shows up 10x slowdown with play-json comparing to jackson-module-scala.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will look for that alternative you suggest.